# How can I relate ‘address’ with other two entity types?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

In a certain business domain, there are three entity types: `Address`, `Merchant` and `Hotel`, and they're related as follows:

- A `Merchant` can have many `Addresses`, and
- a `Hotel` can have only one `Address` at a time.

In my database structure, I want to “use” the same table for both entity types, and I think that I need to have two columns for that, that is to say, `merchant_id` and `hotel_id` in the `Address` table.

I feel this design is not perfect because in many cases either of the two columns would contain NULL marks. What is recommended approach?

Comment: A hotel is a merchant...of hotel rooms

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the same table for entities of the different nature.

In the RDBMS paradygm table represents the *type* or *class*. For each specific type/class you have, you should use the separate table. Sure you can mangle the table by bells and whistles like `entity_type_id`. Sure you can cheat and define your entities in common as "something that have an address(es)".

But the direct and inevitable result of such approach is the complexity and non-obviousness of the queries on that tables. Each time you will be forced to check what exact "subtype" of the entities you deal with. More conditions in the `WHERE`s, more complex `JOIN`s and their `ON`'s and so forth.

Indeed, there are lot of cases when we are forced to denormalize our databases or to break the ACIDity for sake of performance. But if your primary goal is the clear and comprehensible design - you have to avoid violations of the basic principles. Pretty good explanation you can find in the foundational book "An Introduction to Database Systems" by C.J.Date, part II chapter 5.

As mentioned by **Gypsy Spellweaver**, you need an auxilliary "pure relationship tables":

```
+----+-------+-----+    +----+----------+-----+    +----+---------+-----+
| id | Hotel | ... |    | id | Merchant | ... |    | id | Address | ... |
+----+-------+-----+    +----+----------+-----+    +----+---------+-----+

      +----------+------------+    +-------------+------------+
      | Hotel_id | Address_id |    | Merchant_id | Address_id |
      +----------+------------+    +-------------+------------+
```

Here two bottom tables contains nothing but IDs of corresponding hotels, merchants and addresses.

When you want to know what adresses are associated with some hotel your query is:

```
SELECT w.*, z.*
  FROM Hotel    AS w
  JOIN H_A      AS q ON q.hotel_id = w.id
  JOIN Address  AS z ON z.id = q.address_id
 WHERE w.Hotel = "Holiday Inn"
;
```

Query that returns all the hotels and merchants having the same address:

```
SELECT w.*, m.*, z.*
  FROM M_A       AS s
  JOIN H_A       AS q ON q.address_id = s.address_id
  JOIN Hotel     AS w ON q.hotel_id = w.id
  JOIN Merchants AS m ON s.merchant_id = m.id
  JOIN Address   AS z ON z.id = q.address_id
;
```

Comment: I am sure that the merchant and hotel are never going to have same address.

Comment: @CodeYogi That was just an example how straightforward and powerful that approach is.

Comment: I agree but afaik we need third table when there is a many2many mapping in general, wdyt?

Comment: @CodeYogi Those "pure relationship tables" are already implements M2M mapping.

Comment: But in my case there is not any m2m relationship. Hotel and Address is a o2o and Merchant and Address are o2m.

Comment: @CodeYogi If you are absolutely sure that no multiple addresses will be assigned to the same item you have to add the property/column/attribute `address_id` to the corresponding table. If you are not sure and want to avoid future complications you have to use PRTs.